# Selectors for divs with specific data attributes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to use CSS to specifically select divs with specific data attributes. The data attribute I'm using is 'data-id' and selectors I've tried are:

```
div['data-id'*="2"]
div[data-id="2"]
div['data-id'="2"]
```

Nothing works. Can anyone help get the working selector using the 'data-id' attribute to make the 2nd div red? Thanks for any help here.

```css
div['data-id'*="2"] {
  color: red;
}
div {
  color: blue;
}

/* also fails:
div[data-id="2"]
div['data-id'="2"]
*/
```

```html
<div data-id='1'>one</div>
<div data-id='2'>two</div>
<div data-id='3'>three</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be `data-id="2"` Yes, this is works.

```css
div[data-id="2"] {
  color: red;
}
div {
  color: blue;
}

/* also fails:
div[data-id="2"]
div['data-id'="2"]
*/
```

```html
<div data-id='1'>one</div>
<div data-id='2'>two</div>
<div data-id='3'>three</div>
```

Comment: not sure how it didn't work when I tried it, but it works here! thanks...